# Angular $http call not working when session is lost

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I'm having some problems when I try to make some $http calls after the user session has expired. Server side the methods are created in such a way that if a request comes and the user isn't authenticated it redirects to the login page. Making the call with JS doesn't help much because for some method it returns me the HTML mark-up for the login page and for other calls it doesn't work at all. I would like to know why some calls return something and some calls don't do a thing.

**CODE - Call that works**

```
$http({
            url: url + $scope.ftValue,
            method: 'GET'
        })
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            //stuff on success
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("An error occured when applying the Free Text Search!");
        });
```

**Call that doesn't work**

```
$http({
            url: url + '&currentFacet=' + facetName,
            method: 'GET'
        })
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            //stuff on success
        })
        .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("Error during facet values extraction. Status: " + status);
        });
```

To note that the only thing that's different is the method that's getting called. And that's kind of irrelevant because the controller has an authorisation annotation and the call doesn't even reach the method (which is fine, because for the one that works it returns me the login page).

I would like to know what would cause the second call to not work. Both are triggered by an `ng-click` directive.

Comment: how do you route this? (ngRoute)

Comment: I don't use `ngRoute` for this. I construct the url (called on `$http`) before calling a GET on the server. The url (shown in the browser) roughly stays the same on every call.